# convert video to html5 compatible format (server side)

Tags: html, video

I want to create a website that plays videos uploaded by the users in html5 video.

How can I convert any video type on server side to WebM, OGG or MP4?

Is FFmpeg the best solution? So far this is what I think, but I'd much rather find a simpler way.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, ffmpeg is the best solution, but you need to follow the next steps to make video working in all browsers:

1- Download the last version of ffmpeg from here [ffmpeg download](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)

2- Extract the content to a directory;

3- With PHP call the exe file to generate the mp4 and webm video format, like this:

```
exec(ffmpegdirectory/bin/ffmpeg.exe -i your_video_path -qscale 4 -vcodec libx264 -f mp4 your_new_video_path.mp4);

exec(ffmpegdirectory/bin/ffmpeg.exe -i your_video_path -b 1500k -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -ab 160000 -f webm -g 30 -s your_new_video_path.webm);
```

4- Allow in IIS(if it is your case) the Mime Types mp4 and webm

5- Use [video.js](http://videojs.com/) to build the html5 video tag and call your two converted videos (mp4 and webm);

Note: if you don't use video.js, probably the video won't work in IE.

Comment: do you have any examples of the php code you used to make this?

Answer (score 0):

Nice but your coding was a little off RED_ALERT user.

```
        <?php
      shell_exec("ffmpegdirectory/bin/ffmpeg.exe -i your_video_path -qscale 4 -vcodec              libx264 -f mp4 your_new_video_path.mp4");

        shell_exec("ffmpegdirectory/bin/ffmpeg.exe -i your_video_path -b 1500k -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -ab 160000 -f webm -g 30 -s your_new_video_path.webm");
```

?>

so basically your adding ffmpeg to a separate directory folder on your computer and not in wamp if you using wamp. You can than i'm assuming create a html document that srcs the video and shouldn't need video js. Of course you would need to know the path to the video and figure out a way to put the path from the msyql query into the php shell_exec command above.

Here is another example which converts a wmv video into a mp4 video.

```
  <?php shell_exec("ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -i /myvideos/lionseatsham.wmv -s 500x400 -strict -2  /myvideo/lioneatshame.mp4 2>&1");
```

?>