# Which format video upload in my website to make all broswers compatibility

Tags: javascript, html, video, frontend

Firstly, we need upload ourselves, not use youtube.

I know two solutions:

1. html5 -> mp4,ogg,web-m
2. swf -> IE7,IE8

But when an ordinary user upload video, they can't upload four formats. If user upload a **mp4 video**, how to make it have good compatibility in all broswers?

Comment: You could convert the video on your server.

Comment: Can frontend or js convert it?

Comment: While it's possible, there's no sense in converting the video on the frontend. Think about it. The video is going to be uploaded to your server anyway. If you coverted it to a total of 4 different formats, the user would have to upload ~4 times as many bits. Whatever your serverside language is, there's bound to be libraries that let you easily convert videos to other formats.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem once, you will find that `.ffmpeg` is the best solution, just visit the below link.

[convert video to html5 compatible format (server side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706602/convert-video-to-html5-compatible-format-server-side)

Answer (score -2):

Try this code...

```
   <video src="mymovie.mp4" width="320" height="240" controls>
   <video width="320" height="240" controls>
     <source src='mymovie.mp4' type='video/mp4' />
     <source src='mymovie.ogv' type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
     <object id="flowplayer" data="flowplayer-3.2.2.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="320" height="240" >
        <param name="movie" value="flowplayer-3.2.2.swf">
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
        <param name="flashvars" value="config={'clip':{'url':'mymovie.mp4','autoPlay':false}}">
      </object> 
   </video>
```

Comment: How is this relevant to the question?